# PNG metadata 0 dpi

Tags: printing, printf, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

Our printers are looking at the dpi of some of our formatted png files for the purposes of digital garment printing. The files show 300 dpi in Photoshop, but when the same png file is opened in ImageMagick the metadata shows 0 dpi even though the image is clearly present. What could cause this?

My team has no idea where to even start with correcting this problem because it seems to have just started out of nowhere.

Comment: What is your version of Imagemagick and on what OS/platform? Post and example image that has this issue.

Comment: In a PNG the "DPI" is in the well-documented [`pHYs` ancillary chunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks). So it it present and what are the contents?

Comment: Try `exiftool YOURFILE.PNG`